# Can I put a main method in java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.3

Is there a way I can create a `main` method in java (android) and if there is can you please tell me how?

Comment: The `onCreate` Method is the start Method for every activity.

Comment: "Is there a way I can create a main method in java (android)" -- you are welcome to create a method named `main()`, but it will not be used by the framework.

Comment: If i don't put a main class is prints this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: *****.Activity.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Comment: @user9277283 Are you sure your project is configured correctly to use the Android framework? Sounds like it's configured to just use plain ol' Java

Comment: you cannot do this in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **main()** method in java acts as an entry point for the program. In android however there are different methods to define entry points. Such as **onCreate()** for Activities and **onCreateView()** for fragments. So you do not need to have any main() method in android.

Comment: If i don't put a main class is prints this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: *****.Activity.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Comment: As you can clearly read that it says there is no such method called Activity.main([Ljava.lang.String;), so you have defined a wrong method, as there is no such method predefined in activity class. and the other main is the name of thread.